# Un-friending someone on Yelp

Tags: yelp.com

How do I go about un-friending a contact from my list on Yelp?

I searched the Yelp FAQ but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing a friend is listed in their [FAQ](http://www.yelp.com/faq#remove_friend):

> Click on the "Account" link (upper right), then click on "Manage All Friends," pick the Friend you wish to remove, scroll down and click the "Remove Friend" button.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated for 2012 UI:*

- Click your name in the top right
- Choose Account Settings
- Click Friends
- Search for  your Ex YBFF in the list
- Click the gray X to the right of their name

(If you mess up, click the Undo button)